# How to use queryInterface.bulkUpdate from Sequelize when it is necessary to check if a key is present in a jsonb column?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I want to use Sequelize migration to update a table in my Postgres database.

My SQL query uses de `?` operator from Postgres for JSONB columns.

The SQL query I need to run is:

```sql
UPDATE messages SET type = 'products' WHERE type = 'gallery' and content ? '%textMain%'
```

My migration in Sequelize looks like this:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkUpdate(
      'messages', 
      { type: 'products' }, 
      // HERE GOES THE WHERE CLAUSE
    )
  },

  down: async (_queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

After losing some hair looking for an answer.

I solved it doing this:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.bulkUpdate(
      'messages', 
      { type: 'products' }, 
      Sequelize.literal("type = 'gallery' AND content ? 'textMain'")
    )
  },

  down: async (_queryInterface, _Sequelize) => {
  }
};
```

Hope it can help other people with the same problem! :+1

I would love to see other ways to solve this.

Comment: What does that literal is doing? Does it mean it will update type to products whose value is "gallery"? Is it so?